# Get member of __m128 by index?

Tags: c++, clang, sse, simd, intrinsics

I've got some code, originally given to me by someone working with MSVC, and I'm trying to get it to work on Clang. Here's the function that I'm having trouble with:

```
float vectorGetByIndex( __m128 V, unsigned int i )
{
    assert( i <= 3 );
    return V.m128_f32[i];
}
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Member reference has base type '__m128' is not a structure or union.
```

I've looked around and found that Clang (and maybe GCC) has a problem with treating __m128 as a struct or union. However I haven't managed to find a straight answer as to how I can get these values back. I've tried using the subscript operator and couldn't do that, and I've glanced around the huge list of SSE intrinsics functions and haven't yet found an appropriate one.

Comment: It's useful to know that the original intrinsic interface intentionally left out this functionality because there is no efficient way to do it efficiently in the hardware. Compilers (like MSVC) will provide extensions (like `m128_f32`) to do it. But it only masks the performance problem.

Comment: Yeah I understand that it completely removes the benefit of processing the vector at once - I think this particular function isn't intended for heavy use. Since I'm porting though, I'd like to avoid leaving anything unimplemented.

Comment: @Mysticial on gcc, when using -mfpmath=sse (and on msvc when generating 64 bit code), floating point values are in sse registers. You can return the least significant part of a vector efficiently using `_mm_cvtss_f32(V)`, and other elements by first shuffling the desired value into the low element.

Comment: It's worth noting that with newer builds of clang, you can just do `return V[i]`.

Comment: @benwad a note - It's pretty clear that there should be an `[i]` after the `V.m128_f32` - since you say this works on MSVC. And that change obviously doesn't affect the clang error message, and the detail isn't really material to what you're asking. I've tried twice to submit this as an edit to the question, but most reviewers feel that I'm changing the intent of the question, so it's not happening.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A union is probably the most portable way to do this:

```
union {
    __m128 v;    // SSE 4 x float vector
    float a[4];  // scalar array of 4 floats
} U;

float vectorGetByIndex(__m128 V, unsigned int i)
{
    U u;

    assert(i <= 3);
    u.v = V;
    return u.a[i];
}
```

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayeb3ayc(v=vs.71).aspx) says you should not do this, leaving access via [load and set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hey67c0(v=vs.71).aspx) operators.

Comment: @Steve-o: gcc says otherwise: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fstrict_002daliasing-849

Comment: I've seen a lot of contradictory opinions about this approach, but it looks like it's the only viable option on Mac. Thanks!

Comment: It's certainly the most portable way, IME - it works on Mac OS X, Linux, Windows, with gcc, clang, ICC, MSVC, etc.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz It's not clear to me that `u.a[i]` really fits the first "supported" example at your link, and not the second "might not work" example -- since `u.a` produces a `float *` and then the dereferencing is done separately by `[i]`.  I use this technique myself, but I find it pretty annoying that there seems to be no 'official' way to do this kind of type punning (even this here is something that GCC says will work; it's not guaranteed by the language). Is it necessary to actually memcpy one struct to another?

Comment: I'd also add that the use of a union for type-punning is often elided by gcc, so that the implied store & load are not done - in cases where both views of the union fit in a register. So this makes it the most efficient technique for many type puns (in addition to being the safest). But in this particular example, that isn't going to happen since there's no opcode can that extract element [i] from an sse register.

Comment: The union is not well defined in C++; see [Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203) GCC and SunCC have produced bad results with it on occasion. GCC under Aarch64 and SunCC on x86_64.

Comment: @jww: typically any compiler which supports SIMD intrinsics as an extension has to also support the use of unions like this. I believe it's allowed in C99 and later, so it's presumably not too hard to make it work properly in C++ also.

Comment: Fundamentally, *if this does work*, the compiler is doing the heavy lifting and under the hood you will be getting load / store operations simply by accessing the component. It's better to be explicit about when you do the load / store operations because especially on platforms with poor memory bandwidth, this can cause a lot of lost time. And isn't the point of using vectors to optimize?

Comment: @johnb003: compilers are getting surprisingly good at optimising this kind of pattern, but from a performance perspective if you’re doing this kind of thing inside a performance-critical loop then there is probably a better way - typically you only want to access individual elements after a loop, e.g. when performing a reduction operation.

Answer (score 22):

As a modification to hirschhornsalz's solution, if `i` is a compile-time constant, you could avoid the union path entirely by using a shuffle:

```
template<unsigned i>
float vectorGetByIndex( __m128 V)
{
    // shuffle V so that the element that you want is moved to the least-
    // significant element of the vector (V[0])
    V = _mm_shuffle_ps(V, V, _MM_SHUFFLE(i, i, i, i));
    // return the value in V[0]
    return _mm_cvtss_f32(V);
}
```

A scalar float *is* just the bottom element of an XMM register, and the upper elements are allowed to be non-zero; `_mm_cvtss_f32` is free and will compile to zero instructions.  This will inline as just a shufps (or nothing for i==0).

Compilers are smart enough to optimize away the shuffle for `i==0` (except for long-obsolete ICC13) so no need for an `if (i)`.  https://godbolt.org/z/K154Pe.  clang's shuffle optimizer will compile `vectorGetByIndex<2>` into `movhlps xmm0, xmm0` which is 1 byte shorter than `shufps` and produces the same low element.  You could manually do this with `switch`/`case` for other compilers since `i` is a compile-time constant, but 1 byte of code size in the few places you use this while manually vectorizing is pretty trivial.

---

Note that SSE4.1 `_mm_extract_epi32(V, i);` is not a useful shuffle here: `extractps r/m32, xmm, imm` can only extract the FP bit-pattern to an *integer* register or memory (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/extractps).  (And the intrinsic returns it as an `int`, so it would actually compile to `extractps` + `cvtsi2ss` to do int->float conversion on the FP bit-pattern, unless you type-pun it in your C++ code.  But then you'd expect it to compile to `extractps eax, xmm0, i` / `movd xmm0, eax` which is terrible vs. shufps.)

The only case where `extractps` would be useful is if the compiler wanted to store this result straight to memory, and fold the store into the extract instruction.  (For i!=0, otherwise it would use `movss`).  To leave the result in an XMM register as a scalar float, `shufps` is good.

([SSE4.1 `insertps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/insertps) would be usable but unnecessary: it makes it possible to zero other elements while taking an arbitrary source element.)

Comment: This should use `_mm_cvtss_f32` instead of `_mm_store_ss`.

Comment: @Dan: Good point; I missed that intrinsic when I wrote the answer. It makes it more compact, for sure.

Comment: `_mm_extract_epi32` extracts the FP bit-pattern as an integer (in a GP register!), and then converts that integer to `float`.  `_mm_extract_ps` (SSE4.1 `extractps`) does the same thing.  Just remove the `__SSE4_1__` part and this function will be pretty good.

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
template<unsigned i>
float vectorGetByIndex( __m128 V) {
    union {
        __m128 v;    
        float a[4];  
    } converter;
    converter.v = V;
    return converter.a[i];
}
```

which will work regardless of the available instruction set.

Note: Even if SSE4.1 is available and `i` is a compile time constant, you **can't** use `pextract` etc. this way, because these instructions extract a 32-bit integer, not a `float`:

```
// broken code starts here
template<unsigned i>
float vectorGetByIndex( __m128 V) {
    return _mm_extract_epi32(V, i);
}
// broken code ends here
```

I don't delete it because it is a useful reminder how to not do things.

Comment: This is wrong. 1) `_mm_extract_epi32` takes __m128i as its first parameter, you are passing __m128 - the code won't compile. 2) if you solved that with `_mm_castps_si128`, `_mm_extract_epi32` returns the raw floating point value as an integer in a general register (such as eax). 3) That value would be the `int` converted to a float: 1.0f == 0x3F800000 = 1,065,353,216. For `1.0f` your code will return `1.06535e+09` on SSE4. 4) Even if you solved that with casts and reinterpreted dereference, it would be inefficient. Your code uses the wrong intrinsics. Use `_mm_shuffle_ps` and `_mm_cvtss_f32`.

Comment: @doug65536  This code works and compiles actually fine. Do you use MSVC?

Comment: no, I use gcc, I run linux. I even tested it, your code doesn't compile. You probably aren't passing -msse4 to gcc so the `#ifdef` is always false. [I tested it here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5ce00f0c5c8178594df01b391b19558e-983c0f2a174ed37aad33b683cbc6a687) I had to change the `_mm_extract_epi32` to `_mm_extract_ps` for it to compile. Extract gets a value into a general (integer) register with the `movd` instruction.

Comment: You are right, _mm_extract_epi32 does not work for floats - I had taken the code from a similar integer routine without further checking the `#ifdef __SSE4_1__` case. Thank you for your remarks.

Comment: No worries, SSE intrinsics are very error prone. We all make those mistakes.

Comment: The *"better"* way with the union is not well defined in C++; see [Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203). GCC and SunCC have produced bad results with it on occasion. GCC under Aarch64 and SunCC on x86_64.

Comment: @jww: does SunCC support Intel Intrinsics?  I was under the impression that every compiler that supported `__m128` defined the behaviour of union type-punning, C99-style.  GNU C++ and GNU C89 do define the behaviour of this use of unions, so if your testing was having a problem on GCC then you were probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The way I use is

```
union vec { __m128 sse, float f[4] };

float accessmember(__m128 v, int index)
{
    vec v.sse = v;
    return v.f[index];
}
```

Seems to work out pretty well for me.

Comment: The union is not well defined in C++; see [Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203). GCC and SunCC have produced bad results with it on occasion. GCC under Aarch64 and SunCC on x86_64.

Comment: @jww: GNU C++ does define the behaviour of union type-punning in C++ to match C99.  If this failed with GCC, it was either a compiler bug or due to *other* undefined behaviour elsewhere in the program.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html.  (Applies to GNU C++ as per the "Some choices are documented in the corresponding document for the C language. See C Implementation." wording in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Implementation.html.

Comment: This is only GNU C++ of course, not ISO C++, and in GNU / clang implementations of `__m128`, you can simply index the `__m128` itself, like `v[index]`, because it's defined as a GNU C native vector like `typedef float __m128 __attribute((vector_size(16),may_alias));`.  Of course the union hack is portable to some other C++ compilers like MSVC that define `__m128` differently.  So it can be useful, but need to be careful to mention that **it's not strictly portable to all C++ implementations that support Intel intriniscs.**

Answer (score 1):

Late to this party but found that this works for me in MSVC where z is a variable of type __m128.

```
#define _mm_extract_f32(v, i)       _mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_shuffle_ps(v, v, i))

__m128 z = _mm_setr_ps(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);

float f = _mm_extract_f32(z, 2);
```

OR even simpler

```
__m128 z;

float f = z.m128_f32[2];  // to get the 3rd float value in the vector
```

Comment: Yes, MSVC defines `__m128` types as a union of various element sizes.  This is completely non-portable to other compilers like GCC or clang, so I'd recommend against it unless you wrap it in a helper function you can `#ifdef` later for portability.  i.e. do not scatter `.m128_f32` access throughout your code.  Defining a union of `__m128` and `float[4]` will work on MSVC and some (but not all) other compilers, see @Jordan's answer and comments.  Or just `_mm_store_ps` to a tmp array and reload, letting the compiler optimize it into a shuffle if it wants.